# How do I check two conditions in an if NOT statement?

Tags: if-statement, operators, conditional-statements, freemarker

```
<#if page != "News" || page != "Blog">
    <#-- do this --->
</#if>
```

I want to check two conditions in an **if not** statement. I tried using OR logical operator but doesn't work.

When I check one condition only it works.

```
<#if page != "News">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will always return true.

```
<#if page != "News" || page != "Blog">
    <#-- do this --->
</#if>
```

Consider `page = "News"`, the first part will return `false`, while the second part returns `true`, the result of the complete `if` statement is `true`. Then again if `page = "Blog"`, the first part returns `true` and second part returns `false`. Again the complete `if` returns `true`. With any other string you will get `true` from the first part.

Instead you should use

```
<#if page != "News" && page != "Blog">
      <#-- do this --->
</#if>
```

to check if `page` is not `News` and also not `Blog`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sami!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<#if !(page == "News" || page == "Blog")>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if page != "News" and page != "Blog":
    #do stuff
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Theo, I use FreeMarker.

Comment: then I cant help you, sorry, maybe tag your question with your language